# Magento 2 Model file Const get in Helper

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 Model file Const get in Helper.

I want to this type :-

File Path :- **GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source**

```
<?php

namespace GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Landingpageproducts extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean implements ArrayInterface
{

    const VALUE_NO = 'lpage_no';
    const VALUE_NEW = 'lpage_new';
    const VALUE_FEATURED = 'lpage_featured';
    const VALUE_SALE = 'lpage_sale';

    protected $_options;

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => self::VALUE_NO, 'label' => __('No')],
            ['value' => self::VALUE_NEW, 'label' => __('New Products')],
            ['value' => self::VALUE_FEATURED, 'label' => __('Featured Products')],
            ['value' => self::VALUE_SALE, 'label' => __('Sale Products')]
        ];
    }
?>
```

**`Helper code :-`**

```
<?php

namespace GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Helper;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    
    const VALUE_NO = \GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source:: VALUE_NO;
    const VALUE_NEW = \GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source:: VALUE_NEW;
    const VALUE_FEATURED = \GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source:: VALUE_FEATURED;
    const VALUE_SALE =\GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source:: VALUE_SALE;
}
?>
```

Above const value get in Helper file.

So Please Help me how to get const in helper.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

To use these constants variables outside of the class, you can use the full path of the class like below:    \GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source:: VALUE_NO

It starts to be frown upon to use these constants as it give less encapsulation to your code. But it has its pros indeed. Good luck

Comment: Hello @Herve Tribouilloy i have already try but not success. Please provide me other solution .

Comment: I have add mu helper code in  my question. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update below lines in your helper file

```
const VALUE_NO = \GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Landingpageproducts::VALUE_NO;
const VALUE_NEW = \GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Landingpageproducts::VALUE_NEW;
const VALUE_FEATURED = \GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Landingpageproducts::VALUE_FEATURED;
const VALUE_SALE =\GetSomeMojo\CategoryLandingPage\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Landingpageproducts::VALUE_SALE;
```

You missed to add class name there `Landingpageproducts`. Update that and it should work.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if you resolved this issue, or if you need any help then, thanks. ;-)